# How to optimize massive data from ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a social app that shows 20 images per page with the user who posts it, comments for each image and authors of each comment, and also likes for each image with users who likes it

so `image belongs_to user`, `image has_many comments and likes`, `comment belong_to user`, and `like belong_to user`

and in my ImagesController#index i eager load all this like :

```
def index
   @images = Image.includes(:user, likes: :user, comments: :user).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
end
```

the problem here is that all comments with their authors will be loaded, same thing for likes.

Also this is not possible to limit an eager loaded association : from the doc :

> If you eager load an association with a specified :limit option, it
>   will be ignored, returning all the associated objects

So how to optimize my request in this situation ? ( I want for example get eager load 3 comments for each image ), any other suggestion will be helpful. thank you

Comment: That's not how you use `includes`. You use it at the time when you build a query, *outside* the model.

Comment: @meagar don't understand what do you means exactly, can you explain please, an example will be thankful :)

Comment: Else where, like in a controller, you would use `Image.includes(:user, likes: user, comments: :user).order('created_at').limit(20)`.

Comment: @meagar sorry it was just an error of write from me :) now i updated my code

Comment: Your method name is longer than its body. That's not how good code is written. Just write out the includes, if and when you need them :|

Comment: @meagar the name i given here is just to be clearer in reality i use just a short name but no problem i will update it too :)

Comment: `includes` is kind of what the ActiveRecord associations do - it joins two models together (and makes the data accessible from memory), from my understanding

Comment: @RichPeck yes exactly, with that in place you solve problem of N+1 query